# Latex Quit: ! Undefined control sequence. l.62 \@writef

Tags: errors

I was updating my tutor handouts for calculus and suddenly the whole thing refuses to compile.
I have no idea what is wrong or why it is saying this. All I changed were some equations and I added a

```
\begin{aling}
text
\end{align}
```

This is line 62:

```
\let\originaleqref\eqref
```

I use it for `refs`, and it always worked until now.

```
\let\originaleqref\eqref \renewcommand{\eqref}{Eq.~\originaleqref}
\newcommand{\tref}[1]{Table (\ref{#1})} 
\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Fig.
(\ref{#1})}
```

Please help me get this to work! I need to hand this out tomorrow.=/

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I edited to mark your code, but did not change the `aling` to not change the meaning of the post. Is this a copy typo, or the same in your code? That would cause an error.

Comment: Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/FXS1DcbG
Clearing the temp files seems to help, but it starts talking about some missing $'s then, and I have no idea where that could be =/

Comment: @Coolcrab:  This is a lot of code. In order to help people who'll help you, could you please remove everything from the code that's _not_ related to your problem and add a little document, a so-called [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), that people can copy and compile to reproduce your problem? Otherwise, your question might be in danger of being closed as _too localized_.
Please add that MWE to your question by clicking [edit].

Answer (score 2):

Change line 493 of your code to:

```
\item Find d/dx $\rpar{ y \sin(x) = x^3 + \cos(y)}$   %493
```

and on my system (MiKTeX 2.9) it is compiling without errors with `pdflatex`.

I have corrected your `$` for start and end the math mode in that line.